# Issues with setting PostgreSQL up and db:rake

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, linux, postgresql

I've had numerous issues with setting up Postresql for a project I'm working on.

---

Some information:

-I'm running Ubuntu 12.04

-I have a postgres user account installed

-I'm trying to use a project in RoR.

---

I'm trying to use this command:

"bundle exec rake db:create"

I tried using it as sudo, computer user, and postgres.

When I run it as my computer user it returns "fe_sendauth: no password supplied" and then aborts the rake.

I **know** my **(user account)** ruby version is **2.1.0** because when I run "ruby --version", it returns

"ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]"

**However**, when I run "ruby --version" as **postgres**, it returns

"ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]"

How can I have separate ruby versions for my user account and postgres? I tried using sudo to change the ruby version with RVM, but I was denied permission.

I don't remember setting the password for postgres sudo, and I cannot figure it out.

What can I do to

1. Recover/reset my sudo postgres password.
2. Install/set the newest (2.1.0) version of ruby on the postgres account once I have done step 1.
3. Run bundle exec rake db:create after all of that?

Comment: use RVM. Install RVM and you can then install and manage different versions of ruby inside it. So, go for it.

Comment: I have RVM, but I cannot access sudo on the Postgres account in order to use RVM since somehow a password (which I do not know) was set for postgres sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, not sure any specific issues with linux, but it sounds like you have it installed okay.

Hard to say without looking at your database.yml, but the rails convention seems to be to connect to the database with the username <%= your_project_name %> and a blank password. Based on the error, you may not have created such a user/role in postgres.

```
# enter the psql shell as the postgres admin user
psql -d postgres
CREATE ROLE <%= your_project_name %> WITH LOGIN CREATEDB SUPERUSER;
\q

# create the dbs and load the schema
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:schema:load
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare

# revoke superuser, it was just there in case there were any extensions that needed installing
psql -d postgres
ALTER ROLE <%= your_project_name %> WITH NOSUPERUSER;
\q
```

That should do that trick, although it sounds like you might be having issues with RVM as well. There is a ton of documentation on RVM on the website.

You also may be confusing the concept of users/roles in the DB with the concept of users in the OS. You should be able to access the database with any unix user but you need to authenticate rails into the database using database.yml. As noted above, there seem to be defaults that most rails projects i've seen use, but of course you could use whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I fixed my main issue with my ruby version being incorrect and not being able to fix it because I did not have authentication.

I did this with

$ /bin/bash --login

This let me then type

$ rvm --default use 2.1.0

This set my ruby version in user postgres to 2.1.0.

---

**However**, I then tried to run

$ bundle install

in user postgres, and I was denied and given this error

Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at
http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!

/home/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/myusername/.bundler (Errno::EACCES)

I cannot access sudo for user postgres because I did not set the password for it. therefore, I believe that  the answer to my question is to run

$ sudo bundle install

but I do not have the sudo password.

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.